# mailto with empty recipient?

Tags: iphone, email

is there anyway that I can use "mailto" with empty recipient? I only want to supply the subject and the message body and then the user can write the to addresses on mail. I tried writing only a space but it didn't work.

Comment: When you say "didn't work", what do you mean? Does anything at all happen when you click on the link? And can you post the "a href" link you tested with?

Comment: Also, what mail application are you using?

Comment: And thirdly, why do you want this anyway? Are you making a shortcut to send email to anyone? Usually you want people to send an email from a website to a specific mailbox, like a support mailbox or similar. What are you actually trying to implement here? I'm pretty sure most people that use email is clever enough to be able to start a new email by themselves. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: i meant the email application of the iphone couldn't be opened when i left the recipient empty. it s not a href;
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithString: @"mailto:   ?subject=Test&body=Test!"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: [NSURL URLWithString: url]];

Comment: i'm showing football news in my application and i want to add a share functionality to news.every news has a share button at the bottom and  i want the mail application of iphone to be opened with news title as the subject and news as the message content when that share button is clicked. then user can write the to addresses to send.

Comment: sorry, i didnt think that my question could be considered in different meanings. also i didnt say anything about html.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

This should do, I tested it.

```
mailto:?subject=your%20subject&body=your%20body
```

And as HTML with correct escaping of the ampersand:

```
<a href="mailto:?subject=your%20subject&amp;body=your%20body">test</a>
```

Comment: is there a need to escape the ampersand? & -> &amp;

Comment: @DigitalDesignDj No, that's a URL parameter, but your subject and message body will need to be URL encoded.

Comment: @Már Örlygsson see @Xyon's comment - you shouldn't escape the ampersand after `subject` because it's a URL parameter separator, not a literal ampersand.

Comment: Nope, the example shows the URL as part of HTML code - and "&" is a reserved character in HTML and needs to be escaped.
The code example is invalid HTML without &amp;

Comment: The above example *will* work without the &amp; escaping - but only because current browsers adhere to the Robustness Principle and autocorrect this bad HTML.

Comment: Proof: `var link = document.createElement('a'); link.href='mailto:?subject=foo&body=barbar'; console.log( link.outerHTML );`

Answer (score 12):

This should work..

```
<a href="mailto:?subject=My Subject">test</a>
```

Comment: Of all the suggestions, this was one was the working for me. A lot of the other solutions are 5 years old.

Answer (score 9):

I tried the accepted answer but it failed to launch an email when using Chrome. Using a `%20` instead of a space worked though:

`<a href="mailto:%20?subject=Wazzup&body=Yo">Send an Email</a>`

Comment: This worked for me while the others weren't. I was using chrome and my default mail client was outlook 2013 desktop.